# Do the almost identical sentences 你没有他的勤奋 and 你没有他勤奋 have some difference in meaning?

Tags: meaning, difference

The book I'm reading says there is a slight difference of meaning between these two sentences. I can't really grasp the difference. Do you agree with my book?

1. 你没有他的勤奋。
2. 你没有他勤奋。

Comment: Are you able to cite the book and quote their explanation?  It would improve the question.

Comment: Didn't quote the book, because I didn't want to put words in peoples' mouths. I wanted to see what their gut reaction was.

Answer (score 5):

> 你没有他的勤奋。// you don't have his trait of being diligent.

> 你没有他勤奋。// You are not so diligent as he is.

Comment: What about: 他的爸爸， 他爸爸？ Do you see a difference?

Comment: @Pedroski You should put words in a context. Sometimes, the sentence structure would change if we omit 的. The sentence you questioned on is the very example.

Comment: Most adjectives in chinese can be used as nouns. The differences are the context that being emphasized. To me, using adjectives as nouns highlights the adjective.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at these two sentences separately out of context, the former refers to the qualities of A without B's diligent spirit and attitude. The latter refers to A's diligence being lower than B's (the underlying implication is that the former is more like A is not diligent and B is diligent, and the latter is more like A than B is not diligent enough). ）